# Problems with select box name value - possible to hide it?

Tags: php, smarty, html-select

I have a problem with a select box name value. The "name" value of select box post add this value to the GET method. (I don't need the value of name in the GET method).

But other problem is that I get the values of array from the select box name value. If I not setup name value in the select box, then I don't get the values of array in the options of select box.

Here is the part of the code:

```html
<tr>
<td class="{$CLASS}">
<select id=select name=select>
 
{foreach item=player from=$rooster}
  
  {if $club.id == $player.id_club}
  {cycle values="listeven,listodd" assign=CLASS         print=false} 
<option value="{$player.id}">{$player.name}</option>
  {/if}
    
{/foreach}
</select>
</td>
</tr>
```

The current value of Get method: (2 and 7 are the id's of players)

```
?match=182&save=1&select=2&select=7
```

Desired value of GET method:

```
?match=182&save=1&pos_2=othervalue&pos_7=othervalue
```

(as you see I would like to assign id of players to pos_ tag. (I already tried to change the select box name value to pos_{$player.id} but it not works.

Is it possible to get the desired GET method? Or least it is possible to hide somehow the "name" value of select box.
I hope someone could help for me with a good idea. Many thanks.

Comment: Not sure I follow 100% but seems like a lot of options. You could use JavaScript and handle the submit event of the form, crafting whatever you want to send to the server, or you could look at using checkbox inputs with arrayName[] instead of a select.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I changed to select box inputs from checkbox inputs due to difficult editing of data (much faster to select a starting lineup with select boxes than checkbox inputs.(If I use checkbox inputs then I need to pass more chechboxes in every row of players to send other values to server Could you explain how can I handle the submit event of the form, how can I crafting whatever I want to send to the server? I need to use select box due to difficult editing, with select box it is much faster and I can send other values with jquery select)

Comment: [How to Convert HTML Form Field Values to a JSON Object](https://lengstorf.com/code/get-form-values-as-json/)

Comment: Thanks, I read it.